# Visual Studio 2019 starts new processes for "Node.js: server-side Javascript" and never closes old ones

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and the standard React template. I noticed that when I open Visual Studio, there are 4 instances of node.js created. When I run my project, I get an additional 3 (for a total of 7). If I stop execution and then start it again, I get an additional 3 (for a total of 10), and so on. None of the instances are ever closed, even when I shut down Visual Studio.

I noticed this pattern because after several start and stops one day, my computer said it was low on memory, which has never happened before. I think there were about 50 instances of node.js running and I had to "end task" them.

So I'm assuming that Visual Studio should either shut down the 3 instances each time it stops execution, or it should at least reuse the ones that are already open rather than opening new ones. So I was hoping someone might know what's going on. I'm using 10.16.3 for node and 6.11.3 for NPM (so the latest for both).

Comment: I have the same problem and I don't know how resolve this.